# Count in two tables connected with left outer join

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join

I need a little help with an SQL Query. I want to count number of entries in 2 two tables. my first table called tracking_adspace_views got entry from every view of an Adspace I make. At the end of the day I want to count how much entries I have last day. The second table `tracking_clicks` count the clicks on a special adspace. So not every adspace which get viewed has clicks. So at the end I want something like

- Adspace Id 1 has 500 Views and 3 Clicks
- Adspace Id 2 hast 340 Views and 0 Clicks
- and so on...

My tables looks like this

tracking_adspace_views

[image]

tracking_clicks

[image]

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT  '2013-10-31', 
        views.tracking_adspace, 
        COUNT(views.tracking_adspace) AS tracking_adspace_views,                        
        COUNT(clicks.tracking_adspace) AS tracking_adspace_clicks
FROM views
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT tracking_adspace, 
                   COUNT(sub_c.tracking_adspace) AS tracking_adspace_clicks
            FROM tracking_clicks as sub_c
            GROUP BY sub_c.tracking_adspace
          ) AS clicks 
       ON clicks.tracking_adspace = views.tracking_adspace
WHERE views.tracking_time LIKE  '2013-10-31%'
GROUP BY views.tracking_adspace
```

That counts the views right and where clicks are 0 are also counted correct. But if there are clicks in click column I get the value from views. Thanks for your help:)

Regards

Comment: I think your question is not really clear, what kind of results are you expecting and what do you get?

Comment: Why using the `LIKE` wildcard here - `tracking_time LIKE  '2013-10-31%'`

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be doing a count of a values from rows that will be duplicated by the join.

Try something like this:-

```
SELECT  '2013-10-31' AS TrackingDate, 
        views.tracking_adspace, 
        COUNT(views.tracking_adspace) AS tracking_adspace_views,                        
        clicks.tracking_adspace_clicks
FROM views
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT tracking_adspace, 
            DATE(tracking_time) AS TrackingDate,
            COUNT(tracking_adspace) AS tracking_adspace_clicks
    FROM tracking_clicks 
    GROUP BY tracking_adspace
) AS clicks 
ON clicks.tracking_adspace = views.tracking_adspace
AND DATE(views.tracking_time) = clicks.TrackingDate
WHERE DATE(views.tracking_time) = '2013-10-31'
GROUP BY TrackingDate, views.tracking_adspace, clicks.tracking_adspace_clicks
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect you to have a third table named `tracking_adspaces` or something, with a primary key called `tracking_adspace`. If you do, you could do this:

```
select  '2013-10-13' as TrackingDate,
        A.tracking_adspace
        V.views,
        C.clicks
from tracking_adspaces A
left join (
        select tracking_adspace, count(tracking_id) as views
        from views
        where DATE(tracking_time) = '2013-10-31'
        group by tracking_adspace
) V on A.tracking_adspace = V.tracking_adspace
left join (
        select tracking_adspace, count(tracking_id) as clicks
        from tracking_clicks
        where DATE(tracking_time) = '2013-10-31'
        group by tracking_adspace
) C on A.tracking_adspace = C.tracking_adspace
```

If not, you could use

```
select  '2013-10-13' as TrackingDate,
        distinct(A.tracking_adspace)
        V.views,
        C.clicks
from views A
left join ( 
(etc)
```